What would be non-slang equivalent of "copium"?
Lately, I have seen many people use the word "Copium" to refer to the sorts of fallacies and rote lies people often use to soften the blow when presented with defeats or evidence that contradicts their worldview. While I quite like how this word sums up the concept, it is slang (and therefore useless in academic papers.)
Is there a non-slang word, idiom, etc. that sums up the same concept?

"coping strategy"? It seems related to cognitive dissonance, but I'm not sure of a word that fits.

Defence mechanisms are unconscious psychological responses that protect people from feelings of anxiety, threats to self-esteem, and things that they don't want to think about or deal with. [VeryWellMind] But these are unconscious mindsets. // If this fits, I'll make it an 'answer'.

Perhaps "bad faith arguments"

Depending on which kind of academic paper, I think it could be reasonable to "import" a "perfect word" from another dialect or language, with adequate introduction and explanation. Plenty such like schadenfreude, verklempt, je ne sais quoi, etc. have done so so often that they're loan words (or phrases) in their own right and need no introduction. This might be out of place in a paper for a scientific research journal, but just fine the humanities.

@AndyBonner That would work well... if I knew any such words in other languages. Good idea, though.

Sorry, I wasn't clear; I mean "Outside of scientific research findings, if copium expresses my meaning well, I would use it, after some kind of introduction/explanation like 'Ms. Haversham's view of society is distorted by the personal traumas she has allowed to ossify into a worldview—what is best described by the neologistic portmanteau "copium," untruths that allow a certain level of coping by dulling the pain.'" Academic writing doesn't mean pretending that colloquialisms don't exist; you can use "ain't" when quoting Huck Finn. It means not using them as your own voice.

Also, I already regret "neologistic." No need to say it's a new-fangled word; if my writing is read a decade later it won't be by then. (Though most likely rather than enter regular use it will have faded with the tides of TikTok, so the explanation had better explain well.)

It seems kind of politically loaded, originating on 4chan. Although there's a high degree of irony in many such memes, it should probably be avoided unless you want to leap into culture wars.

I'm trying to think of the situation where "copium" is appropriate but the sentiment behind "copium" is. Like it seems like any word that fits the bill here would convey a level of disdain that wouldn't be suited for a paper? E.g. if you find an academic way to convey that another academic is coping & seething, that's still not appropriate. and if you say that the subjects of your paper are coping hard, that calls into question your reliability and bias as a researcher on whatever topic. (And to be clear, I say this as somebody who loves 'cope'/'copium' in a non-academic context.)

Because the short definition of copium given in the question didn't quite align with my own understanding of the term (the summary in the question is far less disparaging then my own understanding of the word), I took it to Urban Dictionary which is a flawed, but often useful, reference for understanding slang.  The most highly upvoted definition given there is

A metaphorical opiate inhaled when faced with loss, failure or defeat, especially in sports, politics and other tribal settings.
The effects of copium include, but are not limited to: extreme rationalizations for the defeat, outlandish theories of conspiracy supposedly perpetrated by the opposing side, extreme rage directed at the other side, unconvincing allegations of fraud and abuse in the system, and rejection of the system as a whole.

Fundamentally, copium is like a drug which one uses to rationalize failure.  There are a few more academic-sounding words which come close to this idea:

rationalizations

the act, process, or result of rationalizing: a way of describing, interpreting, or explaining something (such as bad behavior) that makes it seem proper, more attractive, etc.

I don't think that this is a great match, since copium includes rationalizing, but also other behaviours which might not be rationalization per se, but rationalizations are certainly a part of what is being described as copium, so this isn't entirely unreasonable. (For the record, I see that someone else has offered the same suggestion—I include it here for completeness.)

coping strategies

an action, a series of actions, or a thought process used in meeting a stressful or unpleasant situation or in modifying one’s reaction to such a situation. Coping strategies typically involve a conscious and direct approach to problems, in contrast to defense mechanisms.

or coping mechanisms

an action, a series of actions, or a thought process used in meeting a stressful or unpleasant situation or in modifying one’s reaction to such a situation. Coping strategies typically involve a conscious and direct approach to problems, in contrast to defense mechanisms.

Again, I don't think that this is a great match, as the negative connotations just aren't there, and these suggest a certain amount of conscious will (while copium perhaps describes more unconscious behaviours).

As suggested by the APA dictionary in the above definitions, defense mechanisms

in classical psychoanalytic theory, an unconscious reaction pattern employed by the ego to protect itself from the anxiety that arises from psychic conflict. ... In more recent psychological theories, defense mechanisms are seen as normal means of coping with everyday problems and external threats, but excessive use of any one, or the use of immature defenses (e.g., displacement or repression), is still considered pathological.

This seems like a pretty reasonable match, to me.  The connotations are still different, but perhaps the adjective "immature" gets us there: "taking copium" means "using immature defense mechanisms".  That being said, this seems to be a pretty technical, jargon-y phrase, and might be out of place outside of psychological literature.


I would also suggest that, since copium expresses an idea which is not well-expressed by existing, well-known words or phrases in English, it might be entirely reasonable to simply use "copium", with a little bit of an introductory paragraph indicating what it means and how it is used.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Rationalization is often used in the sense of providing an explanation for something, often without analysis of other motives or possibilities. Merriam-Webster:

: the act, process, or result of rationalizing : a way of describing, interpreting, or explaining something (such as bad behavior) that makes it seem proper, more attractive, etc.

And rationalize (verb) itself includes in its meanings a sense of making excuses:

b
: to attribute (one's actions) to rational and creditable motives without analysis of true and especially unconscious motives

rationalized his dislike of his brother

broadly : to create an excuse or more attractive explanation for

rationalize the problem


Copium often conveys the sense that the person is finding insufficient, fallacious ways to overlook something bad. Those insufficient, fallacious ways are rationalizations (Psychology Today):

Rationalization is the use of feeble but seemingly plausible arguments either to justify something that is difficult to accept or to make it seem ‘not so bad after all.'



Is there a non-slang word, idiom, etc. that sums up the same concept?

To be in denial is the usual phrase:
MW

Phrases
in denial
: refusing to admit the truth or reality of something unpleasant
a patient in denial about his health problems

There is a Wikipedia page on the condition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial

Copium comes directly from from Coping, To Cope
Coping adjective Oxford Dictionnary

That enables somebody to deal with something difficult

Give people coping skills and they are more resilient in future traumas.

A coping strategy/mechanism


In the case of Copium, it's usually when someone employs a strategy of denial and false hope to cope with something that upsets them.

Where does this definition/quote come from? You must cite it.

And you didn't answer the question that was asked, which is "Is there a non-slang substitute?"

To cope/Coping, is not slang like Copium, what are you on about Robert

There are a large number of related (and more precise) words and concepts it would be helpful to understand when trying to use "copium" in a formal context.
You are most likely having a discussion about responses to cognitive dissonance, the psychological discomfort felt when one's beliefs or worldview is challenged or threatened. Rationalization/justification, selective perception, and confirmation bias are all mechanisms a person may use to ease cognitive dissonance without changing their mind, and could be considered specific forms of "copium."
A few additional considerations:

"Copium" is intentionally insulting to the person that is asserted as "using it" - the real point of the slang is that it's an insult. These alternatives can be insulting if used carelessly, but aren't inherently so
Rationalization and justification have other (more commonly used) meanings outside of a psychological context, so keep that in mind
On the other hand selective perception and confirmation bias immediately point the conversation towards psychology. No one already familiar with the terms will mistake your meaning

